# How is the output designed?

Tags: highcharts

I try to built a php file which produces JSON-Array. I want to draw multiple series for Highstock-Series like in this example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)

How is the output designed?

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?          filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?',
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in JSON you should have 3 series like in examples, but json can be built in php as array and then encoded by json_encode() function.

Comment: I need an concret example, e.g. OUTPUT is [1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5] - is this correct?

Comment: [{
                data:[1,2,3]
            },{
            data:[1,2,3]
            },{
            data:[1,2,3]
            }]